# Angular: ngInclude and ngBindHtml is not a known property of div

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Hi I've been trying to learn Angular in the past days and I would like to use ngHtmlBind or ngInclude directives. However, when I use it and serve my app, the console says this:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'ngBindHtml' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
>
> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'ngInclude' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

I am at a loss reading the documentation. Maybe it's because I am using the CLI and directives are called differently (i.e. instead of 'ng-for', it is implemented as *ngFor)?

I tried ngFor and ngIf and they are working correctly. But when I use ngBindHtml and ngInclude, the error shows up.

Here is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SonglistComponent } from './songlist/songlist.component';
import { ChartComponent } from './chart/chart.component';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { SafePipe } from './safe.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SonglistComponent,
    ChartComponent,
    SafePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**chart.component.html**

```
<div class="chart" *ngFor="let song of dataService.currentPlaylist">
    <div class="chart-options">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" (click)="closeChart()"></span>
    </div>
    <h1 class="chart-title">{{song.title}}</h1>
    <p class="chart-artist">by {{song.artist}}</p>
    <p class="chart-key">Key: {{song.key}}</p>
    <div class="chart-body" *ngBindHtml="song.chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you see such directives as `ngHtmlBind` and `ngInclude`?

Comment: @yurzui I was reading the documentation. Here is the link to the ngBindHtml doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: But you are using angular2 aren't you?

Comment: @yurzui Nope. I am using Angular 4 through the CLI.

Comment: Ok i should rephrase: you are using **angular** not **angularjs**

Comment: @yurzui Yes. Would that mean that the built-in directives are different for the two? Is it possible that *angularjs* has ngBindHtml while *angular* does not?

Comment: Well, yes, of course. Those are completely different frameworks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding

Comment: @yurzui Hey man. Thanks for this. It works! If you would post it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh so that's why. I am confused all this time. I am looking at the different documentation. Everytime I Google **angular**, all the **angularjs** docs show up. It's confusing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no built-in directive `ngBindHtml` in **angular**. It's from **angularjs**

You should use `innerHTML` property instead:

```
<div class="chart-body" [innerHTML]="song.chart"></div>
```

Please refer to *Template Syntax* portion of the **angular** documentation (again, not *angularjs*) for more information:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax